# Start an event on particular html section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a value counter which counts 1-20. Problem is it starts counting whenever the page loads/refresh. so viewer can't see the animated counting. How can i start the counting when visitor reach that particular section ( Section id=counter).

**HTML**

```
<section id=counter>
 <div id="talkbubble""><span class="count">20</span></div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.count
 {line-height: 100px;color:white;margin-left:30px;font-size:25px;}
#talkbubble {width: 120px;height:80px;background: red;position: relative;  -moz-border-radius:10px;-webkit-border-radius:10px;border-radius:10px; float:left; margin:20px;}
 #talkbubble:before {content:"";position: absolute;right: 100%;top: 26px; idth: 0;height: 0;border-top: 13px solid transparent;border-right: 26px solid red;border-bottom: 13px solid transparent;}
```

**jquery**

```
$('.count').each(function () {
    $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
        duration: 4000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use scroll event to constantly check if the section is currently in view and this depends on your preference on when exactly you want the animation to start.

When you do this, you have to add something to the element indicating that the animation has already been started and only start the animation if it hasn't already been triggered before.

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function(e) {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= ($("#counter").offset().top - ($(window).height()))) {
    if (!$("#counter").hasClass("animated")) {
      $('.count').each(function() {
        $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
          Counter: $(this).text()
        }, {
          duration: 4000,
          easing: 'swing',
          step: function(now) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
          }
        });
      });
      $("#triggered").addClass("show");
      $("#counter").addClass("animated");
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.count {
  line-height: 100px;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 30px;
  font-size: 25px;
}
#talkbubble {
  width: 120px;
  height: 80px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
}
#talkbubble:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  top: 26px;
  idth: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 13px solid transparent;
  border-right: 26px solid red;
  border-bottom: 13px solid transparent;
}
#counter:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
#filler {
  height: 1000px;
}
#triggered {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, .6);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
#triggered.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="filler"><h1>Scroll down &darr;</h1></div>
<section id="counter">
  <div id="talkbubble"><span class="count">20</span>
  </div>
</section>
<div id="triggered">TRIGGERED</div>
```

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what i always wanted.

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
$('.count').each(function () {
    $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
        duration: 4000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
        }
    });
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/80mjus7x/)

Comment: Sorry to say, I couldn't find any difference between your code and my code. It's doing the same thing. I want to fire this jquery event when my mouse scroll down to counter section.

Comment: I added jquery function 1.9.1 version @AmiHasan

Answer (score 1):

On `scroll` check to see if the top of `#counter` is in the viewport.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  var st = $(this).scrollTop(),
    vh = $(this).height(),
    $counter = $('#counter'),
    ct = $counter.offset().top;
  if ((st + vh) > ct) {
    // #counter is in the viewport
    $('.count').each(function() {
      $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
      }, {
        duration: 4000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function(now) {
          $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
        }
      });
    });
  }
})
```